# I have no idea how to calculate volume of stack of paper since its thickness not given

Tags: derivatives

a stack of pages is growing at a rate of 1 mm per day (that’s 20 pages). How fast is the volume of paper growing when the stack is 50 pages high? (Assume standard A4 page: 210 by 297 mm)

i am confused here by the input given: (lets assume paper =p and time =t)

we have rate of increase per day or dp/dt=1mm or 20 pages

This is what i have come up with:

By the given info 1mm=20 pages

At 50 pages rate of change of height will be 50/20=2.5mm

Length L and Breadth B are constant
Volume =L*B*H or V=LBH

dV/dt=dH/dt

2.5mm

Comment: given rate of growth is the rate of height growth, you need to define how fast the volume grows

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DavidK I don't think he was, only that 1mm worth of sheets are added over the course of one day. For all we know these sheets could be 1nm or 1mm thick.

Comment: If 1mm = 20 pages, then you actually do know the thickness of 1 page.  But as the answer indicates below, you don't need it.

Comment: @DuncanRamage Indeed, "1 mm per day (that’s 20 pages)". I deleted my earlier comment, however, because as observed, if we know the rate in mm per day we don't need to know about the individual pages.

Comment: The "50 pages" part is also irrelevant to the calculation. Lots of unnecessary information in the problem statement, so part of the task of solving it is to figure out what to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the thickness. Let $h, l,$ and $w$ be the height, length, and width, respectively. Since $V = hlw$, by the product rule, $\frac{dV}{dt} = lw\frac{dh}{dt} + hw\frac{dl}{dt} + lh\frac{dw}{dt}$. However, A4 paper itself isn't changing size, so this becomes $\frac{dV}{dt} = lw\frac{dh}{dt}$. All three values on the right are known, so you just need to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the question either makes no sense or is lacking information.

The rate of growth of the volume, $dV/dt$, since the area of the paper stack is constant, is linked to the rate of growth of the height. And this is constant as well. So in the end the rate of groth of volume is the same when the stack is 50 pages high or 1 page high...

It is $dV/dt=A.dp/dt$, with $A$ the area of the pages, and $dp/dt$ the rate of growth of the height.

Comment: It's not that the question doesn't make sense, it's just that the 50 pages bit is a red herring.